# code element with padding extends outside its container

Tags: html, css

When I set the padding on a code element to be large enough, it causes the padding to extend beyond the boundary of its parent container:

html:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="top">
    Top Line
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>
      <code>
        Bottom Line
      </code>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.top {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

code {
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
  padding: 10px;
}

p {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Deepview/ag6977mL/6/

To see this, set the padding on the code element to 30px. It extends upwards and over top of the first line.

This appears to happen because the code element is nested inside a paragraph which is nested inside a div. If I remove the div and paragraph, the problem is corrected and the code element does not extend over the top line. I really need to keep the div and paragraph. How can I avoid this from happening and have the code element always have its inner text move downward if the padding is large?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.top {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

code {
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
  padding: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}

p {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

> You just add display:inline-block;

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this css property to avoid overflow in

```
display:inline-block
```